# Can primary key & field mapped with SubscriberKey can be different in a data extension in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contact, subscriber-key

We've created a custom object "Enquiry" in sales cloud which is child object of "Lead" object. (i.e. Lead represent a unique user)

We've also deployed marketing cloud which is in sync with sales cloud. I want to create a data extension which will be used to send emails on each enquiry. Can I create this data extension in a fashion such that primary key is Enquiry_Id and Lead_Id is mapped with SubscriberKey. (Context - Whenever I create a DE and make any field as Primary Key, Marketing cloud automatically maps primary key with subscriber key).

(Leads are being counted as Contacts in marketing cloud)

Answer (score 1):

I've raised ticket to support for this and got the answer.

You can create a data extension where primary key is different and key which maps to subscriber is different.

For update purpose, primary key will be referred & for contact count, key which is mapped to subscriber key will be referred.